# Timer on a thread in java

Tags: java

I am trying to do the following, call a method `getSessionID()` every **thirty minutes** from the start of execution. The method will be called from a long running service application.

I have been looking at **threads** in java but I am not clear on how to achieve this.

Does anyone have any sample or sudo code ?

Comment: your direction of thoughts are correct, try to dig more into threading. Good luck!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us the relevant code, what you are not clear on and we will try to correct it.

Comment: Have a look at  this. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/UsejavautilTimertoscheduleatasktoexecuteonce5secondshavepassed.htm

Comment: are you sure to use threads here as there are other libraries for timing which can be used instead

Comment: are you trying to scheduling? you have to change your mind from threading to any scheduling technique

Comment: I am looking at couple of concepts, but as I understanding threading is the basic idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [`Quartz`](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) library:

> Quartz is a richly featured, open source job scheduling library that
>   can be integrated within virtually any Java application - from the
>   smallest stand-alone application to the largest e-commerce system.
>   Quartz can be used to create simple or complex schedules for executing
>   tens, hundreds, or even tens-of-thousands of jobs; jobs whose tasks
>   are defined as standard Java components that may execute virtually
>   anything you may program them to do.